# Not getting callbacks for Geofence in DidEnter and DidExit methods. Getting error "error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-location, geofencing

```swift
class LocationManager: NSObject , ObservableObject {
    
    static var shared = LocationManager()
    
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    @Published var currentLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    @Published var currentRegion : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion()
    @Published var checkInStatus : CheckInOut = .checkOut
    
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        addGeofence()
        
        if let status = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "status") {
            checkInStatus = CheckInOut(rawValue: status) ?? .checkOut
        }
    }
    
    func addGeofence() {
        
        let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.5355, longitude: 77.3910), radius: 100, identifier: "Noida")
        
        region.notifyOnEntry = true
        region.notifyOnExit = true
        
        
        if !CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLCircularRegion.self) {
            print("Geofencing is not supported on this device!")
            return
        }
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
    }
}


extension LocationManager : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        LocationManager.shared.currentLocation = manager.location?.coordinate
        if let loc = LocationManager.shared.currentLocation {
            LocationManager.shared.currentRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: loc, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, monitoringDidFailFor region: CLRegion?, withError error: Error) {
        
        guard let region = region else {
            print("Monitoring failed for unknown region")
            return
        }
        
        print("Monitoring failed for region with identifier: \(region.identifier)")
    }
    
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        handleEvent(for: region, checkInStatus: .checkIn)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        handleEvent(for: region, checkInStatus: .checkOut)
    }
    
    func handleEvent(for region: CLRegion , checkInStatus : CheckInOut) {
        
        Api.hitDummyApi(successHandler: {
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UserDefaultsHelper.saveStatus(status: checkInStatus)
                NotificationHandler.createLocalNotificationForCheckInStatus(region: region, checkInStatus: checkInStatus)

            }
        })
    }
}
```

getting error everytime entering or exiting the region. For sometime the code was running fine but after some time it started showing error. I have checked "allow location simulation" in edit schemes section and added custom location as well.
Also it is working if I change location using Xcode simulation but not if I change using iPhone simulator.

Comment: You are never deleting your regions. Each app can only register so many regions (20 from memory).  Check your `monitoredRegions` property https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423790-monitoredregions and remove old regions

Comment: @Paulw11 I checked it is showing only 2 regions. Plus one thing more that sometimes perfectly and then the other time it gives that error. And if I change location from xcode, then it is working but not when I am changing using iPhone simulator.